Pylance in VSCODE Jupiter Notebooks cannot resolve modules
I am working with VSCODE Jupiter Notebooks and Pylance cannot resolve some of the modules that I know they have been successfully loaded into my virtual environment.
Below is an screenshot:

The notebook is using the proper virtual environment:

The code successfully runs. The problem is with Pylance as I think it is somehow confused.
How can I have Pylance acknowledge the library that has been successfully loaded into the virtual environment.

Does this answer your question? Import pandas could not be resolved from source Pylance(reportMissingModuleSource)

@InSync, no it does not. This is about  Jupiter Notebooks not .py source editing.

That question is also about Jupyter.

@InSync, all pip packages are installed in a virtual environment (shown in the shownd screenshot) The .venv is working perfectly in with the .py files. Just one particular notebook that is confused. I just like to learn the root cause, otherwise I can copy/paste code to another notebook and call it he day.

There isn't enough information to justify a definitive answer. Try to reproduce the problem on another machine (e.g. a GitHub codespace) and start from there.

@InSync, VSCODE team from MC are monitoring this tag. This question is for awareness. I am going to spend some time this weekend and drill into this. I can patch it, but its sporadic behavior bothers me. In case I find the answer, I will post here. But

You need to use shortcuts Ctrl+Shift+P and type "Python: Select Interpreter" to choose the venv interpreter first then choose the jupyter kernel.

I am having this issue, I believe it is related to the fact that jupyter is not updating the pylance interpreter when the venv is changed. In the case of this question, I believe if you close and re-open the notebook it will correctly highlight. Like in the debug logs it says "Interpreter for Pylance for Notebook URI "path/to/notebook" is path/to/venv/bin/python. And this will only show up once when first loading the notebook. But if you change the venv this does not re-occur, suggesting that the interpreter is not correctly updating for pylance.

Also, another thing you can try that works for me is disable and then re-enable the jupyter extension without restarting / reloading vscode. It seems to force-refresh the pylance highlighting without restarting the kernel

I do not think this is a mistake, as stated in the document, you have to choose your python interpreter first then select the jupyter kernel.
